# Aggregating time

Tags: r, dataframe

My data contains 1-minute measurements that I would like to aggregate to 5 and 10 minutes. How can I group my data to 5 in 10 minutes considering the Day column as well?

**Sample data 2:**

```
structure(list(Day = c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday"), Time = structure(c(0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 
420, 480, 540, 600, 660, 720, 780, 840, 900, 960, 1020, 1080, 
1140, 1200, 1260, 1320, 1380, 1440, 1500, 1560, 1620, 1680, 1740, 
1800, 1860, 1920, 1980, 2040, 2100, 2160, 2220, 2280, 2340, 2400, 
2460, 2520, 2580, 2640, 2700, 2760, 2820, 2880, 2940, 3000, 3060, 
3120, 3180, 3240, 3300, 3360, 3420, 3480, 3540, 3600), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Measurement = c(1.341667, 2.146667, 
2.683333, 2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 1.61, 1.341667, 3.488333, 3.756667, 3.22, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 2.951667, 2.415, 2.415, 1.61, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 
2.683333, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.146667, 1.341667, 
3.488333, 3.756667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 1.341667, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.415, 
2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 1.341667, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 
2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 1.341667
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_time", 
"collector")), Measurement = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(Day, Time = ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(Time), '5 minutes')) %>% 
  summarise(Measurement = mean(Measurement)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[, .(Measurement = mean(Measurement)),
   by = .(Day, Time = ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(Time), '5 minutes'))]
```